# Create jsf bean in code (Session Listener in this case) causes infinite loop

Tags: jsf, listener, infinite-loop

First of all, All is done in JSF 1.2.
In short, I have this code:

```
public class MobileConfigurationToolSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

@Override
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        externalContext.getSessionMap().put("myBean", new MyBean());
    }
...
}
```

The bean is accessed from the JSF context as a regular JSF session bean.

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.textMsg}"/>
```

The result is an almost infinite loop which finally ends due to:

```
011-04-06 15:47:42,435 WARN  [http-80-1] org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlGridRendererBase PanelGrid GeneralConfigForm:j_id_jsp_1651416019_7:0:GeneralDetailPanel has not enough children. Child count should be a multiple of the columns attribute.
2011-04-06 15:47:42,825 IDT] E 0000000c (org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter#service) An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing
ava.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to create a bean object by my self (According to URL parameters or cookies) in the session listener and "inject" the new bean to the JSF session.

What Am I doing wrong?

### Thanks!

**EDIT**- I thought that another solution could be to make the myBean instantiate somehow by JSF and then run methods on it to achieve the same idea. 
I remember a @BalusC article on how to make JSF instantiate a bean from code but I couldn't find it. (I'm Guessing @BalusC will answer me on this so thanks in advance :-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I have this code:*

As to the listener, you shouldn't access `FacesContext` in there. It is not guaranteed to be present there since the `HttpSessionListener` is not part of JSF. If the session is been created upon a request which does not involve `FacesServlet`, the `FacesContext#getCurrentInstance()` will return `null`.

The correct way would be

```
event.getSession().setAttribute("myBean", new MyBean());
```

---

> *The result is an almost infinite loop which finally ends due to:*

As to the infinite loop, the repeating part of the stacktrace is more interesting than the ending part. I suspect that this is caused by another bug.

---

> *What I'm trying to achieve is to create a bean object by my self (According to URL parameters or cookies) in the session listener and "inject" the new bean to the JSF session.*

As to the functional requirement, just declare the bean session scoped and do the desired job in its constructor or `@PostConstruct`. Whenever you reference it in the view, its constructor and `@PostConstruct` will run. You have access to the request parameters and cookies just there.

```
public MyBean() {
    // Constructor.
    Map<String, String> params = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap();
    Map<String, Object> cookies = externalContext.getRequestCookieMap();
    // ...
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // Or here, if you're dependent on managed properties.
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I guessed that was the answer but wanted the advice from the pro :-)